# spring amqp rabbit - no receiver by default

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I'm building two applications, one for publishing messages to RabbitMq and another for consuming the messages from RabbitMq.

I got started with [spring's getting started with rabbitmq](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/)

The problem: 
The tutorial creates one application that registers to rabbit as a publisher AND as a consumer.

I just can't find a way to start an application only as a publisher.
This is how I tried to configure the bindings:

```java
    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(WeatherRequestQueue.QUEUE_NAME);

        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);

        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(WeatherQueryListener receiver) {
        return null;
    }
```

Note that I return null from the `listenerAdapter()`. This is my attempt to not register a consumer..

I get the following error when trying to remove the listener:
`Parameter 1 of method container in my.packag.QueryBinding required a bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter' that could not be found.`

Comment: try this one https://www.baeldung.com/rabbitmq-spring-amqp I think it's much better tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the listener container bean. It is only needed on the consumer side.

Answer (score 0):

I was following the same tutorial and got the same exception. And with my experience, I can say that the comments made by Gary is correct. And to address the question, I would like to say that one can use RabbitTemplate to make the application act as publisher. In the [spring's tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/), have a look about this part of code.

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(MessagingRabbitmqApplication.topicExchangeName,
                "foo.bar.zoo",
                "Hello from RabbitMQ");
```

Above code sends the message "Hello from RabbitMQ" to the routing key "foo.bar.zoo"